# Agregar transición suave al mostrar texto

Tags: css, animación

Lo que quiero lograr es un efecto menos duro cuando se muestra el texto, agregar una clase con alguna transición o animación para que el texto aparezca de a poco y no se vea tan duro.

Estoy usando React y quiero crear esta clase para el componente `Tour`, la info esta en el `p`. No sé si debería agregar la clase al párrafo o al botón que está en el `span`, o qué transición sería la adecuada.

¿Cómo agregar una clase que haga una transición suave al hacer click en un botón que muestra más texto?

Éste es el código:

```js
class Tour extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showInfo: false
  }

  handleInfo = () => {
    this.setState({
      showInfo: !this.state.showInfo
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { city, img, name, info } = this.props.tour;

    return ( 
      <article className = "tour">
        <div className ="card">
          <img src = {img} className = "img-fluid card-img-top" />
          <span className = "close-btn">
            <i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
          <div className="card-body">
            <h3>{city}</h3>
            <h4>{name}</h4>
            <h5>info{" "}
              <span onClick={this.handleInfo}>
                <i className="fa fa-arrow-down" ariaHidden="true"></i>
              </span>
            </h5>
            {this.state.showInfo && <p>{info}</p>}
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    );
  }
}
// CC BY 2.0 Wikipedia
ReactDOM.render(
  <Tour tour={{ city: "Jaén", img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Ja%C3%A9n-loc.svg", name: "Capital del Santo Reino", info: "Jaén es una ciudad y municipio español de la comunidad autónoma de Andalucía, capital de la provincia homónima. Ostenta el título de «Muy Noble y Muy Leal Ciudad de Jaén, Guarda y Defendimiento de los Reinos de Castilla»" }} />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir tour.css? ¿Qué es lo que has intentado?

Comment: He editado tu pregunta para que el código sea ejecutable y he quitado las etiquetas de JavaScript y React. Esto es realmente un "problema" de estilos que aplicaría igual fuera con React o no. Sin definir la animación que estás intentando, esta pregunta queda como muy amplia y subjetiva. No debe ser cualquier animación sino la que quieras en concreto: ¿aparecer poco a poco? ¿crecer verticalmente/horizontalmente? ¿volar desde arriba? ¿una combinación de varias? Es por eso que es importante que compartas más detalles sobre lo que quieres y lo que hayas intentado. Lee [ask] para más información-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar keyframes:

```css
@keyframes fade-in {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.info {
  opacity: 0
  animation: fade-in 5s forwards;
}
```

Ejemplo: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-shamir-2vbz1?fontsize=14

O podemos usar el componente `Transition` de la librería `react-transition-group`:

```
<Transition in={showInfo} timeout={duration}>
  {state => (
    <p
      style={{
        ...defaultStyle,
        // devolvemos el estilo especifico del estado
        // que nos interesa
        ...transitionStyles[state]
      }}
    >
      Información a mostrar
    </p>
  )}
</Transition>
```

Ejemplo: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-flower-kpfvh?fontsize=14